# how to scale the histogram plot via matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

You can see there is histogram below.
It is made like 
`pl.hist(data1,bins=20,color='green',histtype="step",cumulative=-1)`
How to scale the histogram?
For example, let the height of the histogram be one third of it is like now.

Besides, it is a way to remove the vertical line at the left?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The matplotlib `hist` is actually just making calls to some other functions. It is often easier to use these directly allowing you to inspect the data and modify it directly:

```
# Generate some data
data = np.random.normal(size=1000)

# Generate the histogram data directly
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, bins=10)

# Get the reversed cumulative sum
hist_neg_cumulative = [np.sum(hist[i:]) for i in range(len(hist))]

# Get the cin centres rather than the edges
bin_centers = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:]) / 2.

# Plot
plt.step(bin_centers, hist_neg_cumulative)

plt.show()
```

The hist_neg_cumulative is the array of data being plotted. So you can rescale is as you wish before passing it to the plotting function. This also doesn't plot the vertical line.