# Plotting CDF of a pandas series in python

Tags: python, pandas, series, cdf

Is there a way to do this?  I cannot seem an easy way to interface pandas series with plotting a CDF.

Comment: Could you define your problem? What's the input and output? scipy.stats have the cdf functions you might be interested in.

Comment: There was a feature request for this, but it's outside pandas' domain. Use [seaborn](http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/plotting_distributions.html#basic-visualization-with-histograms)'s `kdeplot` with `cumulative=True`

Comment: Input is a series, output is a plot of a CDF function.

Comment: When I check out seaborn, I get this error "Cumulative distributions are currentlyonly implemented in statsmodels.Please install statsmodels. 
"

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In case you are also interested in the values, not just the plot.

```py
import pandas as pd

# If you are in jupyter
%matplotlib inline
```

## This will always work (discrete and continuous distributions)

```py
# Define your series
s = pd.Series([9, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5, 8, 7], name = 'value')
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
```

```py
# Get the frequency, PDF and CDF for each value in the series

# Frequency
stats_df = df \
.groupby('value') \
['value'] \
.agg('count') \
.pipe(pd.DataFrame) \
.rename(columns = {'value': 'frequency'})

# PDF
stats_df['pdf'] = stats_df['frequency'] / sum(stats_df['frequency'])

# CDF
stats_df['cdf'] = stats_df['pdf'].cumsum()
stats_df = stats_df.reset_index()
stats_df
```

[image]

```py
# Plot the discrete Probability Mass Function and CDF.
# Technically, the 'pdf label in the legend and the table the should be 'pmf'
# (Probability Mass Function) since the distribution is discrete.

# If you don't have too many values / usually discrete case
stats_df.plot.bar(x = 'value', y = ['pdf', 'cdf'], grid = True)
```

[image]

Alternative example with a sample drawn from a continuous distribution or you have a lot of individual values:

```py
# Define your series
s = pd.Series(np.random.normal(loc = 10, scale = 0.1, size = 1000), name = 'value')
```

```py
# ... all the same calculation stuff to get the frequency, PDF, CDF
```

```py
# Plot
stats_df.plot(x = 'value', y = ['pdf', 'cdf'], grid = True)
```

[image]

## For continuous distributions only

Please note **if it is very reasonable to make the assumption that there is only one occurence of each value in the sample** (typically encountered in the case of continuous distributions) then the `groupby()` + `agg('count')` is not necessary (since the count is always 1).

In this case, a percent rank can be used to get to the cdf directly.

**Use your best judgment when taking this kind of shortcut! :)**

```py
# Define your series
s = pd.Series(np.random.normal(loc = 10, scale = 0.1, size = 1000), name = 'value')
df = pd.DataFrame(s)
```

```py
# Get to the CDF directly
df['cdf'] = df.rank(method = 'average', pct = True)
```

```py
# Sort and plot
df.sort_values('value').plot(x = 'value', y = 'cdf', grid = True)
```

[image]

Comment: That's answer it's very detailed and helpful.

Comment: This is helpful indeed. Thank you!

Comment: How do I define the number of bins in this answer?

Comment: There are no bins to be defined. No histogram here if that is what you are thinking.

Answer (score 95):

I believe the functionality you're looking for is in the hist method of a Series object which wraps the hist() function in matplotlib

Here's the relevant documentation

```
In [10]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [11]: plt.hist?
...
Plot a histogram.

Compute and draw the histogram of *x*. The return value is a
tuple (*n*, *bins*, *patches*) or ([*n0*, *n1*, ...], *bins*,
[*patches0*, *patches1*,...]) if the input contains multiple
data.
...
cumulative : boolean, optional, default : False
    If `True`, then a histogram is computed where each bin gives the
    counts in that bin plus all bins for smaller values. The last bin
    gives the total number of datapoints.  If `normed` is also `True`
    then the histogram is normalized such that the last bin equals 1.
    If `cumulative` evaluates to less than 0 (e.g., -1), the direction
    of accumulation is reversed.  In this case, if `normed` is also
    `True`, then the histogram is normalized such that the first bin
    equals 1.

...
```

For example

```
In [12]: import pandas as pd

In [13]: import numpy as np

In [14]: ser = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=1000))

In [15]: ser.hist(cumulative=True, density=1, bins=100)
Out[15]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x11469a590>

In [16]: plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there a way to just get the step function and not have the bars filled in?

Comment: That'd be `histtype='step'` which is also in the `pyplot.hist` documentation truncated above

Answer (score 20):

I came here looking for a plot like this with bars *and* a CDF line:
[image]

It can be achieved like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
series = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=10000))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(series, bins=100, normed=False)
n, bins, patches = ax2.hist(
    series, cumulative=1, histtype='step', bins=100, color='tab:orange')
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

If you want to remove the vertical line, then it's explained how to accomplish that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24371729). Or you could just do:

```
ax.set_xlim((ax.get_xlim()[0], series.max()))
```

I also saw an elegant solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39306779) on how to do it with `seaborn`.

Comment: maybe the second axis should be in percentage (between 0 - 1)

Comment: @skibee That's a good suggestion. Feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 16):

A CDF or cumulative distribution function plot is basically a graph with on the X-axis the sorted values and on the Y-axis the cumulative distribution. So, I would create a new series with the sorted values as index and the cumulative distribution as values.

First create an example series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ser = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=100))
```

Sort the series:

```
ser = ser.sort_values()
```

Now, before proceeding, append again the last (and largest) value. This step is important especially for small sample sizes in order to get an unbiased CDF:

```
ser[len(ser)] = ser.iloc[-1]
```

Create a new series with the sorted values as index and the cumulative distribution as values:

```
cum_dist = np.linspace(0.,1.,len(ser))
ser_cdf = pd.Series(cum_dist, index=ser)
```

Finally, plot the function as steps:

```
ser_cdf.plot(drawstyle='steps')
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to append the last value?

Comment: `order` is deprecated. Use `ser.sort_values()`.

Comment: @kadee `ser[len(ser)] = ser.iloc[-1]` does not work on pandas 0.19

Answer (score 14):

This is the easiest way.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Series([i for i in range(100)])
df.hist( cumulative = True )
```

[Image of cumulative histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MXSW.png)

Answer (score 7):

I found another solution in "pure" Pandas, that does not require specifying the number of bins to use in a histogram:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np # used only to create example data

series = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=10000))

cdf = series.value_counts().sort_index().cumsum()
cdf.plot()
```

Comment: Nice answer! but cdf should be from 0 to 1; I'd change to `cdf=series.value_counts().sort_index().cumsum() / series.shape[0]`

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading the answer of @wroscoe

```
df[your_column].plot(kind = 'hist', histtype = 'step', density = True, cumulative = True)
```

You can also provide a number of desired bins.

Answer (score 2):

To me, this seemed like a simply way to do it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

heights = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=100))

# empirical CDF
def F(x,data):
    return float(len(data[data <= x]))/len(data)

vF = np.vectorize(F, excluded=['data'])

plt.plot(np.sort(heights),vF(x=np.sort(heights), data=heights))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to plot a "true" empirical CDF, which jumps exactly at the values of your data set `a`, and with the jump at each value proportional to the frequency of the value, NumPy has builtin functions to do the work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def ecdf(a):
    x, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
    y = np.cumsum(counts)
    x = np.insert(x, 0, x[0])
    y = np.insert(y/y[-1], 0, 0.)
    plt.plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps-post')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig('ecdf.png')
```

The call to `unique()` returns the data values in sorted order along with their corresponding frequencies. The option `drawstyle='steps-post'` in the `plot()` call ensures that the jumps occur where they should. To force a jump at the smallest data value, the code inserts an additional element in front of `x` and `y`.

Example usage:

```
xvec = np.array([7,1,2,2,7,4,4,4,5.5,7])
ecdf(xvec)
```

Another usage:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[7,1,2,2,7,4,4,4,5.5,7]})
ecdf(df['x'])
```

with output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I really like [the answer by Raphvanns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317197/13716814). It is helpful because it not only produces the plot, but it also helps me understand what pdf, cdf, and ccdf is.

I have two things to add to Raphvanns's solution: (1) use `collections.Counter` wisely to make the process easier; (2) remember to sort (assending) `value` before calculating pdf, cdf, and ccdf.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
```

Generate random numbers:

```py
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1000, size=(1000)))
```

Build a dataframe as Raphvanns suggested:

```
dic = dict(Counter(s))
df = pd.DataFrame(s.items(), columns = ['value', 'frequency'])
```

Calculate PDF, CDF, and CCDF:

```
df['pdf'] = df.frequency/sum(df.frequency)
df['cdf'] = df['pdf'].cumsum()
df['ccdf'] = 1-df['cdf']
```

Plot:

```
df.plot(x = 'value', y = ['cdf', 'ccdf'], grid = True)
```

[image]

You may wonder why we have to sort the `value` before calculating PDF, CDF, and CCDF. Well, let's say what would the results be if we don't sort them (note that `dict(Counter(s))` automatically sorted the items, we will make the order random in the following).

```
dic = dict(Counter(s))
df = pd.DataFrame(s.items(), columns = ['value', 'frequency'])

# randomize the order of `value`:
df = df.sample(n=1000)

df['pdf'] = df.frequency/sum(df.frequency)
df['cdf'] = df['pdf'].cumsum()
df['ccdf'] = 1-df['cdf']

df.plot(x = 'value', y = ['cdf'], grid = True)
```

This is the plot:

[image]

Why did it happen? Well, the essence of CDF is "The number of data points we have seen so far", citing [YY](http://yongyeol.com/)'s lecture slides of his [Data Visualization](https://yyahn.com/dviz-course/) class. Therefore, if the order of `value` is not sorted (either ascending or descending is fine), then when you plot, where `x` axis is in ascending order, the `y` value of course will be just a mess.

If you apply a descending order, you can imagine that the CDF and CCDF will just swap their places:

[image]

I will leave a question to the readers of this post: if I randomize the order of `value` like above, will sorting `value` after (rather than before) calculating PDF, CDF, and CCDF solve the problem?

```
dic = dict(Counter(s))
df = pd.DataFrame(s.items(), columns = ['value', 'frequency'])

# randomize the order of `value`:
df = df.sample(n=1000)

df['pdf'] = df.frequency/sum(df.frequency)
df['cdf'] = df['pdf'].cumsum()
df['ccdf'] = 1-df['cdf']

# Will this solve the problem?
df = df.sort_values(by='value')

df.plot(x = 'value', y = ['cdf'], grid = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be complex. All it takes is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = series.dropna().sort_values()
y = np.linspace(0, 1, len(x))
plt.plot(x, y)
```