# Plot CDF + cumulative histogram using Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram, ecdf

Is there a way to plot the CDF + cumulative histogram of a Pandas Series in Python using Seaborn only? I have the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
s = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=1000))
```

I know I can plot the cumulative histogram with `s.hist(cumulative=True, normed=1)`, and I know I can then plot the CDF using `sns.kdeplot(s, cumulative=True)`, but I want something that can do both in Seaborn, just like when plotting a distribution with `sns.distplot(s)`, which gives both the kde fit and the histogram. Is there a way?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.randn(200)
stat = "count"  # or proportion
sns.histplot(x, stat=stat, cumulative=True, alpha=.4)
sns.ecdfplot(x, stat=stat)
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can get almost the same plot using matplotlib by using `cumulative=True` and `density=True`.

`plt.hist(x,cumulative=True, density=True, bins=30)`