# How to plot several cumulative distribution functions from data in a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, cumulative-sum

I am trying to create a python script that reads a CSV file that contains data arranged with sample names across the first row and data below each name, as such:

```
sample1,sample2,sample3
343.323,234.123,312.544
```

From the dataset I am trying to draw cumulative distribution functions for each sample onto the same axis. Using the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv


def isfloat(value):
    '''make sure sample values are floats
    (problem with different number of values per sample)'''
    try:
      float(value)
      return True
    except ValueError:
      return False

def createCDFs (dataset):
    '''create a dictionary with sample name as key and data for each
    sample as one list per key'''
    dataset = dataset
    num_headers = len(list(dataset))
    dict_CDF = {}
    for a in dataset.keys():
        dict_CDF["{}".format(a)]= 1. * np.arange(len(dataset[a])) / (len(dataset[a]) - 1)
    return dict_CDF

def getdata ():
    '''retrieve data from a CSV file - file must have sample names in first row
    and data below'''

    with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ',' )
        #create a dict that has sample names as key and associated ages as lists
        dataset = {}
        for row in reader:
            for column, value in row.iteritems():
                if isfloat(value):
                    dataset.setdefault(column, []).append(value)
                else:
                    break
        return dataset

x = getdata()
y = createCDFs(x)

#plot data
for i in x.keys():
    ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
    ax1.plot(x[i],y[i],label=str(i))


plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

This gives the output below, which only properly displays one of the samples (Sample1 in Figure 1A).

[Figure 1A. Only one CDF is displaying correctly (Sample1). B. Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2I7k.png)

The number of values per sample differ and I think this is where my problem lies.

This has been really bugging me as I think the solution should be rather simple. Any help/suggestions would be helpful. I simply want to know how I display the data correctly. Data can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/jZ6QxURA).  The expected output is shown in Figure 1B.

Comment: What is the expected cdf for sample2 and 3?

Comment: I have added an image of the expected output as generated in Excel

Comment: I still only see the previous image, should there be more than one link?

Comment: Apologies. Fixed it.

Comment: I'm guessing you aren't reading all the data from the CSV, check x.shape and see that it is what you expect.

Comment: I am reading all the data from the CSV, I checked it all as I went along. The problem is not in importing the data, although I seem to be importing white space for the two samples that do not contained less data than the other sample - which could be part of the problem. It could also be in the `createCDFs` function or in the way that I am plotting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach. That of course depends on if you want to use pandas. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577352/plotting-cdf-of-a-pandas-series-in-python) approach to calculate cum dist

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

data_req = pd.read_table("yourfilepath", sep=",")
#sort values per column
sorted_values = data_req.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())

#plot with matplotlib
#note that you have to drop the Na's on columns to have appropriate
#dimensions per variable.

for col in sorted_values.columns: 
    y = np.linspace(0.,1., len(sorted_values[col].dropna()))
    plt.plot(sorted_values[col].dropna(), y)
```

In the end, I got the figure you were looking for:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks very much. This works well EXCEPT the data sorting does not seem to be working. I added an unsorted sample to the CSV and your code did not sort the added sample. But it worked once I sorted the original data. Any ideas?

Comment: Also. I'm fairly noob when it comes to Python so I didn't actually know about the panda package - so thank you for that!

Comment: I found the solution to the sorting problem. I replaced your sorting code with the following:
`arr = data_req.values`
`arr.sort(axis=0)`
`data_req = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=data_req.index, columns=data_req.columns)`