# Python matplotlib: customize the y-scale of a histogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code in Python (3.4) Jupyter Notebook to plot a histogram:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

bins = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 40)
plt.hist(list1, bins, alpha = 0.5, color = 'b')
plt.show()
```

I am wondering can I rescale it so that the y-axis value has the maximum value of 100? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369931/how-to-scale-the-histogram-plot-via-matplotlib

Comment: Possible duplicate, not sure if I interpreted the question correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

bins = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 40)
y = np.random.rand(100) 

plt.hist(y, bins)
plt.ylim((None, 100))  # This line sets the y-axis limits

plt.show()
```